# How to find the first and last non-zero values for column and row in an image?

Tags: matlab, indexing, find

I'm having trouble, because I have this image, what I want to do is just work with the pixels that aren't black. But I have to find the first and last nonzero values to define the boundaries were I will work, the problem is that I can find the first nonzero values(rowandcolumn), but in  the last for the column appears the value 1799,and my image is 499x631x3 uint8 , and it should be 533. What is the problem??

My code below:

```
%Find where the image begins and starts
[r_min, c_min]=find(movingRegistered(:),1,'first');
[r_max, c_max]=find(movingRegistered(:,:),1,'last');
```

Image link https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fkwi3xbicwzonz/registered%20image.png?dl=0

Comment: Do you want to find the row corresponding to the first and last nonzero values of each column? Or the way around? Or...?

Comment: I want to find the row and column that define the "rectangle" of the image with information where  the information about the image starts and ends. These are the only pixels that matter to me. please see the image link.

Answer (score 1):

To find the row index corresponding to the *first* nonzero element of each column:

```
A2 = logical(any(A,3)); %// reduce to 2D array, which equals 0 if all three color
                        %// components are 0, and 1 otherwise
[~, row_first] = max(A2,[],1); %// the second output of `max` gives the row index of
                               %// the first maximum within each column
```

To find the *last*:

```
[~, row_last] = max(flipud(A2),[],1); %// matrix upside down to find last, not first
row_last = size(A,1)-row_last+1; %// correct because matrix was upside down
```

To find the first and last in *linear indexing* sense: compute `A2` as above and apply your code to that:

```
[r_min, c_min]=find(A2,1,'first');
[r_max, c_max]=find(A2,1,'last');
```

Comment: Thanks but that is different from what I want. My image have a "rectangle" with information, and other parts that are in black, I just want to define the "rectangle of information" to work only with that pixels. What I want is the first and last nonzero values of all the image. And I don't undersatand why my code gives the value 1799 for col_last,if ,my image is 499x631x3 uint8 . Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Oh I see. Try `A2 = logical(any(A,3));` and apply your code to `A2`. I think that should work